# Cakephp : troubles getting Ajax variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I plan on using Ajax in my cakephp app to update content on a select change, however, for now I just want to return a string, and I sadly can't get it to work,

Here's a look at my code

view:

```
 //triggered on a select change
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'getPrices')); ?>',
    beforeSend: function(xhr)
    {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    },
    success: function(response)
    {

    console.log(response);//returns the empty echo from get_prices.ctp
    console.log(response.testdata);//returns undefined

    },  
    error: function(e)
    {
    console.log(e);
    }   
});
```

controller:

```
public function getPrices()
{
    //$this->request->onlyAllow('ajax'); //tried with and without this

    $testdata = 'testvalue';



    echo json_encode($testdata);
    //also tried : $this->set(compact('testdata'));
}
```

get_prices.ctp:

```
<?php
if(!empty($testdata))
{
    echo $testdata;
}
else
{
    echo "empty";
}
```

`console.log(response);` outputs "empty" from my echo in get_prices.ctp

`console.log(response.testdata);` outputs "undefined".

What my browser's network tab has to say:

```
General
Request URL: http://localhost:8888/myapp/pages/getPrices
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:8888
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response
empty
```

Comment: so what do you get?

Comment: oh sorry, guess it's not that readable that way, will edit, I get the "empty" from my echo in get_prices.ctp, and undefined from console.log(response.testdata);

Comment: Have you checked ajax response in your browser's Network tab?

Comment: just did, I get a 200

Comment: Edited with browser's network tab

Comment: Just to get that out of the way, controllers should never echo data! That being said, make sure that you've enabled debug mode, also check your logs, an empty response often indicates some kind of swallowed error (or the application isn't being invoked at all, and for example the server software intercepts the request for whatever reason).

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have debug enabled, but there's no error being written in the logs

Comment: I'm back at checking it and realized one thing : my getPrices() in pagescontroller is ignored ? I mean, It doesn't go through it, I can delete it, it'll still work, it goes straight to the get_prices view(which of course makes the variable empty if it doesn't go through controller)

Answer (score 0):

Return a encoded array

```
echo json_encode(['testdata'=>$testdata]);
```

Comment: mmh this doesn't change the outputs my console.log give "empty" for `console.log(response)` and "undefined" for `console.log(response.testdata)`

Comment: try adding `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before the echo

Comment: Same result sadly

Answer (score 0):

Okay finally got it working,

First, I had to edit my routes.php, while I did declare my getPrices action there, it was conflicting with this line

```
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

getPrices was declared after, and thus, ignored, so I just declared it before this line.

Then updated my controller:

```
public function getPrices()
{

    $this->autoRender = false;
    $testdata = 'testvalue';

    echo json_encode(['testdata'=>$testdata]);
}
```

and the ajax in my view :

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'getPrices')); ?>',
    datatype: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: {myVar:'Success'},
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('success');
        var decodeddata = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(decodeddata.testdata);
    },
    error: function(){console.log('failed');}

});
```

And it works.
Wouldn't have done it without people's contribution here, thanks.